# No external sound on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, audio

I have Ubuntu 9.10. Headphones appear to work fine. External speakers - nothing. There are so many sound preferences I have no idea what or which combination.

Went to terminal and ran `alsamixer` which seems to recognize my sound card, though the driver is not listed in System > Administration > Hardware Drivers; the only driver listed is my graphics card.

I have tried several forums and it seems no one is interested in responding to sound issues.
Here's hoping it is different here.

Answer (score 1):

> Have you tried running alsamixer in a
>   terminal? Alsamixer seems to be the
>   most reliable for me at this point
>   until updates come down....

so just open a terminal and digit

alsamixer

> Alsamixer quickie tips: left - right
>   to navigate up - down - change levels
>   M - key - toggle mute/unmute B - key -
>   balance channel pairs

Take care :)

Update kernel:

> type in terminal:
>   `uname -r`
>
> Next find available kernel images typing in terminal:
>
> `sudo apt-cache search linux-image`
>
> Now install kernel by explicitly
>   specifying version number typing in terminal:
>
> `sudo apt-get install linux-image-x.x.x-xx`

Comment: Re: alsamixer. Master is at 100%, PCM is at 100% and mute is off.

Comment: Whoooops!

Did you try updating kernel?!

Comment: Now you have me. I am somewhat pc savvy but no geek. I have no idea how to do that, and is that the problem?

Comment: Appreciate your help Pitto. But could you be more specific. I typed in -r and it says command not found. Okay maybe I am not that savvy...lol

Comment: Oh no....have you abandoned me?

Comment: Sorry I got a phone call :D

you should type uname -r :)

Comment: Yikes, gives me a long list. how do i know what i want/need?

Comment: I'd get the newest :)

Comment: Another question: why 9.10?

What about trying a 10.04 (LTS) from livecd to see if it works out of the box?

Comment: The long story short. Windows crashed. Geek friend iped hard drive and installed ubuntu, which I had heard of but never used. Have no complaints except for this sound issue. So i should go to9 ubuntu.com and download a newer version?

Comment: While waiting your response I tried  the kernel this is what it said:

Comment: $ sudu apt-get install linux-image-2.6.31-22
No command 'sudu' found, did you mean:
 Command 'tudu' from package 'tudu' (universe)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)
sudu: command not found

Comment: That should be `sudo`, with an **o**. You should be able to upgrade your installation of Ubuntu to a newer version using the Update Manager. @Walter

Comment: By the way: to make sure people know you've left them a message, reference them with an @ sign. [Here's information on how that works.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) @Walter

Comment: I am upgrading now via Update Manager. Say about 1/2 hour. I hope you two stick around, I am thrilled you are trying to help.@Pitto,@oKtosiTe

Comment: Keep up the good work! :D

Comment: Any (hopefully good) news? :)

Answer (score 1):

Are your speakers active or passive?

If they are active then they'll need an external source of power. If they are passive then they'll take the power from the audio output, but that might not be enough to drive them.

Also (though this is a bit obvious) check that you've got the speakers plugged into the correct output of your sound card. Some have separate outputs for speakers & headphones etc.

Comment: Active (plugged in). Almost positive but tried all, nothing. Could my preferences be set up wrong, tho I have tried all combinations. Very frustrating.