# Still no external sound after installing ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, usb, ubuntu-10.04, audio, sound-card

[As suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/254856/no-external-sound-on-ubuntu-9-10) I upgraded. Same as before except now not even the speaker control in the application bar. Please help.

---

**Background:**

I have Ubuntu 9.10. Headphones appear to work fine. External speakers - nothing. There are so many sound preferences I have no idea what or which combination.

Went to terminal and ran `alsamixer` which seems to recognize my sound card, though the driver is not listed in System > Administration > Hardware Drivers; the only driver listed is my graphics card.

---

**Setup:** I have a Dell 8250. Speakers are plugged into the SB live card. Woofer and 2 speakers using transformer.

Comment: Can you provide some information about your setup?

Comment: @Nathaniel Bannister: Dell 8250 Sound worked fine with windows, friend installed 9.10 no sound, so upgraded as suggested, still no sound and worse.

Comment: How are the speakers connected?

Comment: They are plugged into the SB live card. Woofer and 2 speakers using transformer.

Comment: I did go to alsamixer and pushed the master and pcm? to 100$

Comment: Was your upgrade an upgrade or a clean install? Does the sound work from a live cd?

Comment: It was an upgrade from the Upgrade Center. I have not tried to play a CD, doing that now.

Comment: No sound from CD either, sigh.

Comment: @Nathaniel Bannister: No sound from CD either. Do you get my comments or do I have to @you every time?

Comment: @Walter I've got a few leads, apparently that card is known to be finicky under Linux in general. Is there an on-board sound card as well?

Comment: @Nathaniel Bannister:Not to my knowledge. I switched to a different port in the sound card and have some sound but loudest at the lowest setting and one side only, no left and no sub. And now the headphones don't work at all, tho they were fine with 9.10

Answer (score 1):

I've gone all over the place looking for answers, so far this is what I've turned up:

- The Dimension 8250 had a OEM Soundblastr live that needed non-standard drivers, even under windows
- I'm reasonably sure that the part in question is a Sound Blaster Live! CT4780
- Some suggested that while windows output audio on the black port, ubuntu's driver wants it on the green port
- Some aged suggestions suggested switching alsa for [OpenSound](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSound)
- I'm not sure how in depth you want to get into this, if there's an onboard, I'd probably just remove the add-on card
- If you're feeling adventurous you can try: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

I'll keep an eye on the thread

Comment: @Nathaniel Bannister: Thanks for your efforts. It came with that card so I doubt if there is another. How about aiding with a partition so I can install windows again?

Comment: @Walter, if you look at the back of the machine, is there a second set  of ports? https://img.skitch.com/20110309-dsq85wg32re9nqysj9arciu6ia.jpg

Comment: @Walter if you want to reinstall windows, it's usually easier to wipe with windows, as it's boot manager will erase grub. If you want to dual boot linux after that, then you'd just install again and tell it to split the disk.

Comment: @Nathaniel Bannister: As to the former, unfortunately no.

Comment: @Nathaniel Bannister: As to the latter. Beyond my pay grade my friend. A friend wiped my hard disc after a problem. Installed Ubuntu, which as I have said, no probs except for sound. Which is a biggie, I am so tired of hunching over with my headphones, tho no longer a problem as they no longer work. Anyway, I tried to install windows again and it will not, and I assume the reason is there is no partition. I did download gparted-live-0.7. But it does not give me a workable interface. So, no sound...back to Dell for a new pc?

Comment: @Nathaniel Bannister: Oh and congrats. Read on TC that (you guy's), not you. Just got 12 mil from VC's. I had no idea, I was with the elite. Congrats again.

Comment: @Nathaniel Bannister: Check out Sebastian on Boing Boing. French tecno artist. Not my genre but I loved it.

Comment: @walter if you need help installing windows, let me know the version and I'll see if I can help, though it might be best to move it to a new question.

Comment: @Nathaniel Bannister: xp from a Dell cd. As mentioned I think the main problem is partitioning.